# Multiple uniqueness cases in first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm having some trouble representing the following situation:

There are three persons of unique names: Lars, Kirk and James. Each person drinks a unique beverage: beer, vodka and whiskey. Each person drives unique cars (brand): Mercedes, BMW and Wolkswagen. It is known that:

- James drinks whiskey
- Kirk drives BMW
- The man driving BMW drinks beer
- The person who drives Mercedes also drinks vodka.

I think I can represent the situation as follows (correct me if I'm wrong):

- $Whiskey(James)$
- $BMW(Kirk)$
- $\forall(x) BMW(x) \rightarrow Beer(x)$
- $\forall(x) Mercedes(x) \rightarrow Vodka(x)$

It is stated that only one person can drive BMW (like the other cars as well). Do I have to specify uniqueness for all of the variables, that is for drinks and car brands like the following?

- $\exists x (BMW(x) \wedge \neg \exists y (BMW(y) \wedge x \ne y)) $

Or is there a shorter approach to state the uniqueness of all these things?

Comment: Whiskey, this means it's Irish. Does James drink Jameson? :-)

Comment: If you can use binary predicates, you could have $Drives(m,c)$ (representing that man $m$ drives car $c$) and say $(\forall m) Man(m)\Rightarrow (\exists c)(Car(c) \wedge Drives(m,c))$ (every man drives some car) and $(\forall c)(\forall m_1)(\forall m_2) (Drives(m_1,c)\wedge Drives(m_2,c) \Rightarrow m_1=m_2)$ (no car is driven by more than one man) or something similar.

Comment: @PeterKošinár Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I'd gladly accept it as an answer.